# Refreshing a filter in a table every time slicers update

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a sheet with slicers that refer to a pivot on another sheet. On my sheet with slicers they update a table which references said pivot.

The ask is that, when I change the pivots for new information, it filters out all the blank rows within a range. I need it to re-apply every time I switch something in the pivots to make sure I'm always showing up-to-date data.

This is what I've tried in multiple formats but nothing seems to do the trick:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
If Target.Column = 5 Then
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
End If 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**The following sample code will help you to Filter the Pivot Table when the Slicer is being updated.**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)

 Dim Sheet as WorkSheet, Pivot as PivotTable

 If ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Region").SlicerItems("East").Selected = True Then

   For Each Sheet in ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets
     For Each Pivot in Sheet.PivotTables
     Pivot.RefreshTable
     Pivot.Update
     Next
   Next

End Sub
```

**NB: I've assumed the Slicer Cache & Item name, you need to modify both according to your values.**

*I do hope this help you.*